# npm: not found when creating a reactapp using NVM, NPM, in Pycharm

Tags: linux, reactjs, npm, pycharm, nvm

I am trying to create a `React` project in pycharm. I am using `NVM` version 0.34.0, and installed `node` using it.

Here is my pycharm window before starting a project

[image]

`npm -v` return 6.9.0

`whereis npm` returns  `npm: /home/usa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.3.1/bin/npm`

Here is the error message

```
/home/usa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.3.1/bin/node /home/maged/.nvm/versions/node/v12.3.1/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js .

Creating a new React app in /home/usa/Desktop/ny/untitled1.

/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

events.js:177
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm',
  path: 'npm',
  spawnargs: [
    'install',
    '--save',
    '--save-exact',
    '--loglevel',
    'error',
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'react-scripts@0.9.x'
  ]
}
Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed npm and you can see its version, but you should add it to PATH variable in your system so other services can find it. 
first run this in your terminal

```
cat $PATH
```

check the output to see npm path there if it wasn't there run below command and try again

```
export PATH=$PATH:/<path-to-npm-bin>/npm/bin
```